# Auto deploy with gitlab continuous integration

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab, digital-ocean

I want to setup auto deployment from a gitlab branch to a digitalocean droplet. I created a runner and exec git clone in droplet. But now I can't configure my gitlab-ci.yml for autodeploy from branch "dev" to droplet.

My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:3.5
staging:
  type: deploy
  only:
  - dev
  script:
  # there must be some kind of connection to the droplet to further code executed already on server
  - git pull
  # - server restart
```

How do I connect to the server in gitlab-ci.yml to make "git pull" command?

Comment: i don't want it on digital ocean server, its a local windows server i have setup,

Comment: @Oliver, can you look in to the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I solved the problem. First, we need to add **the GitLab CI runner** to the server. You can see in the documentation how to do it. Then all commands from gitlab-ci.yml will execute on the server. So "git pull" command also will be executed on the server where **the runner** was started.

Comment: what you meant is i have to install git ci runner on my local server? my local server have global static ip also.